How is a question about logic a duplicate of a question about math?
Question about logic: Under physicalism, what is the ontological status of the laws of logic, and what is their relationship to the laws of physics?
Question about math: How does physicalism interpret mathematical theorems in physicalist terms?
My own argument inside the first question:

Addressing the charge of duplicate: this question is NOT about mathematics
This question is about logic, not mathematics. Assuming an equivalence between logic and mathematics is controversial, see:

Can mathematics be reduced to arbitrary axioms and logic?
What is the difference between logic and mathematics?
What is the philosophical ground for distinguishing logic and mathematics?


A supporting comment from a user who thinks the same:

I voted to reopen. Mathematics is clearly not logic and logic clearly not mathematics, notwithstanding what many if not most academics may say. So the question is not a duplicate of the one on How does physicalism interpret mathematical theorems in physicalist terms. Leave your blinders at home for a change. – Speakpigeon


I agree. Equivalence of mathematics and logic is somewhat controversial, so they are different questions. Subjectively, doubting the reality of basic logic feels like a bigger step than doubting the reality of mathematical objects like circles. A variant of mathematical fictionalism holds that mathematical statements may be true while the objects they refer to are not real, so the ontological status of the statements, expressed in some logic, is a different question from the ontological status of the objects. Get 4 reopen votes and tag me and I'll be the 5th.

One thing you should know: Speakpigeon has a very peculiar view on what logic is and what not. On a community level, this is hardly in your favour. As far as I know, he is pretty alone here with his beliefs.

@PhilipKlöcking How about Conifold or Mauro ALLEGRANZA?

@user80226 I do not see anything opposing what I wrote there. Conifold clearly distinguishes between historical and contemporary use of the term logic and Mauro states they are not reducible. I do nowhere state that they are the same, yet the view of Speakpigeon, which is that all logic is and has to be material and has nothing to do with mathematics (basically the ancient view, if at all) is equally problematic.

@causative We  have 4 reopen votes now ;)

Playing devil's advocate here, it could be wrong to reduce this to "math vs logic".

On the material side, laws of logic and mathematical theorems can be seen as very closely related when it comes to physicalism since they are general rules about the operation of abstracts.

Because of that, it could well be that the thread used in the close reason provides an answer that does equally well apply. And that's the only thing that matters! If another thread offers a comprehensive answer to the question at hand, it can and should be marked as duplicate.


Generally, I would ask all sides and individuals of every "camp" about moderation here to stand back from one's own take and ask oneself whether the other side may not have a point before starting Meta threads about everything.

"it could well be that the thread used in the close reason provides an answer that does equally well apply. And that's the only thing that matters!" I don't think that makes sense. To use a simple example, if one question asks "what's five plus three" and another asks "what's four times two," they are not duplicate questions even though the answer to both is "eight."

@causative Thats because your example, contrary to the case at hand, does not treat two cases that are equal in the sense described above. From a physicalist viewpoint, all abstracts have the very same ontological status.

Supposing it's true that all abstracts have the same ontological status under physicalism - and I'm not so sure about that, and it's not like all physicalists have the same perspective on it - consider this example then. One question asks, "are dogs mammals?" and another asks, "are cats mammals?" Someone answers the first question with, "yes, all warm blooded animals with hair that give live birth and nurse their young are mammals." This would answer the second question too, and is analogous with "abstracts : warm blooded etc." and "ontological : taxonomical," but it's not a duplicate.

@causative For me, it would, actually. Since both are asking about what makes mammals mammals.

Most certainly if there was a valid question about dogs in philosophy, I don't see why this community would have to bear a duplication by script of that question for every other of the billion species of animals on earth.
